# How to replace full content of a git local directory with remote directory (but not all repo)?

Tags: git

Simplifying, I have a repository that has multiple directories, of course: `Dir1`, `Dir2`, ...

I want to do a `git pull origin <remote_branch>`, but in such a way that `Dir1` from `remote_branch` will completely overwrite `Dir1` from local, no matter the contents of the local `Dir1`. Every other directory should behave normally as with a normal pull (i.e., conflicts, updates, whatnot).

Could this be done in an elegant manner using git only?

Comment: No, it can't be easily done in one command.

Comment: well I wouldn't expect to be able to do it in one command, but stil, perhaps a multi-command flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since git 2.23 you have a new featue git restore

```
git restore --source=origin --staged --worktree -- <pathspec>
```

this work as a reset hard for one or more directory it replace index and working tree

you can pass more than one directory:

```
git restore --source=origin --staged --worktree -- dir2 dir3
```

for the path you can search the pathspec in the doc https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary

the path can also be defined in a file using --pathspec-from-file=

```
git restore --source=origin --staged --worktree  --pathspec-from-file=pathspec.txt
```

in the file keep attention to the whitespaces

> dir2
>
> dir3

Comment: `git checkout` can do the same?

Comment: yes it is possible  git checkout origin/master -- <pathspec>

Comment: also the part related the pathspec from file is valid for checkout